# DragBehavior only work for the first time with on_touch_up in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

When I use DraggableImage class (a class which inherits DragBehavior and Image) with on_touch_up, once I dragged and dropped a image, the image cannot be dragged anymore.

I don't know why this happens and how to fix.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.behaviors import DragBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class DraggableImage(DragBehavior, Image):
    def on_touch_up(self, touch):  # without this (e.g. "pass" here), image is always draggable.
        print("This is test")

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

test.kv

```
BoxLayout:
    DraggableImage:
        source: "example.png"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `on_touch_up()` method, you should add a call to

```
super(DraggableImage,self).on_touch_up(touch)
```

since you are overriding the `on_touch_up()` method in DragBehavior.

Comment: The `on_touch_up()` method has a return value, so you should handle the return from from DragBehavior.on_touch_up().